# WPF animation not working

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, animation

I'm trying to animate a loading screen while thread is working in background, but it won't work.

I realized that it has something to do with the backgroundworker calling Button.Dispatcher, however I can't remove it, because it would cause threading error. What should I do to fix this?

below is my code:

```
        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)FindResource("Loading");
            sb.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => sb.Begin()), DispatcherPriority.Normal, null);

            BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
            bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);
            bg.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(RunThread));
            thread.Start();            
        }

        private void RunThread()
        {
            btnLogin.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => TheBackgroundWork()), DispatcherPriority.Normal, null);
        }
```

Update:

I remove UI calls from Do_Worker as suggested by Jay. Unfortunately I'm still getting an error:

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

It was thrown by my webservice client

below is the updated code:

```
        private WebServiceClient proxy = new WebServiceClient();

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            sb = (Storyboard)FindResource("sbLoading");
            sb.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => sb.Begin()), DispatcherPriority.Normal, null);

            BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
            bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);
            bg.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bg_RunWorkerCompleted);
            bg.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var u = e.Result;
            if (u != null)
                //pass the data
        }

        private void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var u = proxy.ToWebService(x,y); //this guy throws an error
                e.Result = u;
            }
            catch
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(
                    () => MessageBox.Show("Connection Error", this.Title)), 
                    DispatcherPriority.Normal, null);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you spawning a new thread from the background thread?

Comment: I added it to test if this would fix the UI animation problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `bg_DoWork` method will already be running on a background thread, so no need to create a thread in there.
2. Nothing in `bg_DoWork` should touch UI elements nor anything databound to UI elements. If you have some return data, package it up into an object and stuff it into the `DoWorkEventArgs.Result` property.
3. Add another handler for the `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` event. This method will run back on the UI thread, so you can read your response data from the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` (this will be the result object that you assigned in #2) and update the UI as necessary.

The beauty of `BackgroundWorker` is that it will handle thread creation and marshaling of data back to the UI thread -- no need for any `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

#### Update

In response to your edit, the web service call may be throwing an exception, but the thread exception you get is caused by trying to access `this` from a background thread.

Just as you'd have to package your success result in `DoWorkEventArgs.Result`, you'd need to package a failure result there too.

The object you pass back can be anything, so you can add things like a `bool Success` property, an `Exception CaughtException` property, *etc.*

You'll check these values in your `RunWorkerCompleted` handler and that is where you would show your `MessageBox`.

Comment: @johnte I've added to my answer in response.